# Maintain order when dynamically adding components to page with ngFor

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-components, ngfor

In a parent container, I have a list of strings. This list of strings is used in the template to generate child components. A bit simplified, it looks like this:

*Component*

```ts
export class MyComponent {
    private queries = [];
    private currentQuery: string = 'SELECT * FROM something';

    runQuery() {
        this.queries.unshift(this.currentQuery);
    }
}
```

*Template*

```html
<div>
    <textarea [(ngModel)]="currentQuery"></textarea>
    <a (click)="runQuery()">Click Me</a>
</div>

<div *ngFor="let query of queries">
    <my-child-container [query]=query></my-child-container>
</div>
```

This works, I can dynamically generate my child components on the page. But it's not maintaining the order I want. You'll notice I used `unshift()`, that's because I want new queries to appear *above* old queries on my page layout. Despite the use of `unshift()`, new queries are appearing below the old queries. It appears that `ngFor` ignores the order of the list?

To explain a bit clearer, this is how the new child components are currently appearing on the page:

```html
<div>I'm the 1st query you ran</div>
<div>I'm the 2nd query you ran</div>
<div>I'm the 3rd query you ran</div>
```

What I would like is:

```html
<div>I'm the 3rd query you ran</div>
<div>I'm the 2nd query you ran</div>
<div>I'm the 1st query you ran</div>
```

How can I make Angular2 respect the order of the list? Or am I taking the wrong approach to this?

Comment: Angular2 `*ngFor` builds your DOM elements in the exact same order as they are in the array you pass to `*ngFor`. I'm pretty sure there is something else going wrong. Can you reproduce in a Plunker?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Is that true even for dynamically generated content? I will try to reproduce in Plunker.

Comment: What do you mean with dynamically generated content? Components added by `*ngFor`? Then yes, this is what I'm talking about.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Sorry, what I mean is, even when I'm adding values to the array during run time? The array is not generate once, values are constantly added to when the user is using the app.

Comment: You can add `<div>{{queries | json}}</div>` somewhere on your compoennt to see what `queries` exactly looks like currently.

Comment: When you modify the array, `*ngFor` adds or removes the element at the position where the items were added/removed in the array. That's always exactly sychroniced.